# RegEx in VB (Excel) - how to decode this

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Having read this very useful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) on how to use RegEx within MS Excel, I am now stuck in generating the required expression to cover following scenarios - Any help appreciated.

Objective: I want to be able to split strings like the ones below:

Example 1:

> `AB12345|AB56789x89402` --->  `AB12345`  `AB56789` `89402`   (each of the three to be stored in different cell and the total number of sub-strings is not known in advance, could be from 0 to 10)

Example 2:

> `#AB03925#` to be stored as `AB03925`

Example 3:

> `(ABC-SR-XYZ)|(ABC-XYZ)` to be stored as `ABCXYZ`

Is it possible to have all of the above examples handled through a single RegEx?

So far I have created the following which partially handles cases like example 1:

```
    strPattern = "(^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{5})([|]*[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{5})"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = C.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            C.Offset(0, 1) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")
            C.Offset(0, 2) = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$2")
        End If
    End If
```

However I still do not know how to get rid of the pipe (|) when printing those two strings separately.

Comment: Perhaps match all the values and replace hyphens with an empty string `(?:[A-Z][A-Z])?\d+|[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{3}` [Test](https://regex101.com/r/3vOV2g/1/)

Comment: Why should `(ABC-SR-XYZ)|(ABC-XYZ)` be stored as `ABCXYZ` and not as `ABCSRXYZ` in one cell and `ABCXYZ` in another cell? To write a regex, we need some uniformity in rules

Comment: To find a solid RegEx in most cases one example of each type is not enough. Can you provide a real example data set?

Comment: Probably something like https://regex101.com/r/cfMoAQ/1, and then check which `SubMatches` matched, and post-process the value as required. You can't just throw  in a regex and get your results anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested, here is a non-regex solution.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function ConvertCustomText(InputString As String) As Variant
    Dim CharactersToReplace As Object: Set CharactersToReplace = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Character           As Variant
    Dim HasDash             As Boolean

    With CharactersToReplace
        .Add "#", vbNullString
        .Add "(", vbNullString
        .Add ")", vbNullString
        .Add "-", vbNullString
        .Add "x", "|"
    End With

    HasDash = IIf(InStr(1, InputString, "-", vbBinaryCompare) > 0, True, False)

    For Each Character In CharactersToReplace
        InputString = Replace(InputString, Character, CharactersToReplace(Character))
    Next

    ConvertCustomText = IIf(HasDash, _
                            Split(InputString, "|")(UBound(Split(InputString, "|"))), _
                            Split(InputString, "|"))
End Function

Public Sub Example()
    PrintArrayOrText (ConvertCustomText("AB12345|AB56789x89402"))
    PrintArrayOrText (ConvertCustomText("#AB03925#"))
    PrintArrayOrText (ConvertCustomText("(ABC-SR-XYZ)|(ABC-XYZ)"))
End Sub

Private Sub PrintArrayOrText(VariantInput As Variant)
    Dim i As Long

    If TypeName(VariantInput) = "String" Then
        Debug.Print "Output is " & VariantInput
    Else
        For i = LBound(VariantInput) To UBound(VariantInput)
            Debug.Print "Output is " & VariantInput(i)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

It returns:

```
Output is AB12345
Output is AB56789
Output is 89402
Output is AB03925
Output is ABCXYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

For **example 1** & **2**  this regex works
`[A-Z]{2}\d{5}|\d{5}`
The proof in [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%5cd%7b5%7d%7c%5cd%7b5%7d&i=AB12345%7cAB56789x89402%0d%0a%23AB03925%23).
[image]

To get different results, you can use across columns, using the column to set the result index.

```
If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
    Set matches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
    Dim resultSetIndex
    resultSetIndex = Application.Caller.Column - x ' x is your first column

    If resultSetIndex < matches.Count Then
        RegxFunc = matches(resultSetIndex).Value
    Else
        RegxFunc = ""
    End If
    Else
        RegxFunc = "not matched"
End If
```

`Application.Caller.Column` is used to determine the result index.
You need to set `x` where you place the column. In below example, `x` is **7**.
[image: column to result set]
For **example 3** you need to elaborate more on the rule(s) for extraction.
It isn't entirely clear at this point.

Comment: Thanks, however I am getting an error with Application.Caller.Column and also not sure whether by "x" you mean I should define a variable or just replace x with column 2 in the code itself.

Comment: replce "x" with the 1st column integer. In the above example, its 7.